# Get specific row's td value in which all tr having same class

Tags: jquery

I have the following table structure:

```
<th>
    <td>Qty</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Total</td>
</th>

<tr class="myclass"> --> First row
    <td>3</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>30</td>
</tr>

<tr class="myclass">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>30</td>
</tr>
```

If I click on any row, I want to get the second td's value of the clicked row.
For example if I click the first row, I have to get the price value `10` on that row.
I have tried like below, but it returns `1015`

```
$(document).on('click','.myclass',function(){
  var value = $('.myclass td:nth-child(2)').text();
  console.log(value); // returns 1015
});
```

Also I don't have any idea that how to use 'this' keyword in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue is that your HTML is invalid. `th` should be contained within a `tr`, and does not have `td` as children.

The issue itself is because you're selecting *all* the `.myclass` elements in the click handler. Instead, use the `this` keyword to reference the one which was clicked, then use `find()` from there to get the `td` you want to target. Try this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.myclass', function() {
  var value = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="myclass">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="myclass">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Rory, It works like a charm. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You should get the **td** of the clicked row like below,

```
$(document).on('click','.myclass',function(){
  var current_tr = $(this);
  var value = current_tr.find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
  console.log(value);
});
```